# why do things stick to surfaces when left for a really long time?

Tags: classical-mechanics, everyday-life

I tried to move a cardboard box off the top of a cabinet, which left it on for probably years, and it was insanely difficult to remove. I don't know why this happens, but it also seems that my feet get stuck to the floor if I leave them there for enough time and put enough weight on them. It can't be a pressure differential, like when trying to get paper off a flat surface, because it's much too strong, so what mechanism could be behind this?

Comment: Hypothesis 1: You haven't cleaned your floors in a long time and this is all the dirt and grime setting in a some type of glue or epoxy

Comment: clean and dry floors don't generally do what you are describing

Comment: I think this involves some difficult-to-model physico-chemistry. Cardboard is not a 'pure substance' but a complicated mix of ingredients each with a specific purpose to meet the cardboard's specifications of strength, appearance etc. Over time, some waxy/gluey ingredients (process aids, binders etc) may migrate to the surface and thus the interface between the cardboard and the cabinet surface, thereby creating a 'physico-chemical bond' (for want of a more accurate term) between the two surfaces. That bond may be experienced when moving the box after some time.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_welding

Comment: Seriously @Asher? When did cardboard and wood become *...two clean, flat surfaces **of similar metal*** and when did a typical household cabinet become *a vacuum*?? (all italics from your link).

Comment: @KyleKanos are those the only acceptable conditions between adhesion between two surfaces? Also from my link: *Cold welding was first recognized as a general materials phenomenon in the 1940s.* Lots of things stick together for lots of reasons without being clean flat metals. Note also I gave the link in a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Asher: those are conditions for *cold welding*, not general adhesion or even *this specific* situation. I thought your comment is absurd, hence my comment as a response and not a downvote.